# Java - White space with Integer.valueOf() causes java.lang.NumberFormatException

Tags: java, type-conversion, whitespace

If you try:

`Integer.valueOf(" 00");`

...a java.lang.NumberFormatException is thrown.
So, this is easy enough to fix by stripping any white space, even for a Java noob like me, but I'd very much appreciate any light that can be shed on why the Integer.valueOf() method was designed this way?

Wouldn't you want it to ignore white space?  After all, the white space can't be considered ambiguous in the context of extracting an integer value from the string.  If I'm missing something about this choice, I'm sure an explanation will help me grow as a coder.  Thank you!

Comment: Because space is just a character. A character that isn't a digit. Also you should use `Integer.parseInt(String)` which returns an `int`. `Integer` is a wrapper type (and generally slower than the primitive `int` type).

Comment: The method’s job is to interpret a string as an integer.  Spaces are not numeric notation.  If you want to scan for an integer value in a character stream, there are other classes for that, like [Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If u look at the java docs , `Integer.valueOf(String)` calls

```
return Integer.valueOf(parseInt(s, 10));
```

and according to Java docs again for `parseInt`

> The characters in the string must all be ***decimal* *digits***, except that the
>   first character may be an ASCII minus sign '-'('\u005Cu002D') to
>   indicate a negative value or anASCII plus sign '+' ('\u005Cu002B')
>   to indicate a positive value.

Space violate the above rule hence number format exception.